# using spannablestring to append an image left of the text

Tags: android, image, xamarin, textview, inline

I want to show an image in my textview, in front of the text itself. I tried `CompoundDrawable` but the text of the second lines does not go under the image at the first line.

I would need something like this:

```
var imageSpan = new ImageSpan(this, Resource.Drawable.Icon); //Find your drawable.
var spannableString = new SpannableString(textView.Text); //Set text SpannableString from TextView
spannableString.SetSpan(imageSpan, textView.Text.Length -1, textView.Text.Length, 0); //Add image at end of string
```

But the image in the beginning instead of at the end.

Comment: Have you tried android:setDrawableLeft in XML?

Answer (score 5):

```
Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I don't know why, but 0 and 1 looks important:

```
sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout